# Android Studio Soap Xml Request format not printing

Tags: android, android-ksoap2, httpsurlconnection, httptransportse, android-httptransport

The below Android soap xml request/resposen is printing in Eclipse. But, In Android Studio, Response is print, Request in XML format not printing.
mySample Code:

Android Ksoap Xml request

AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

```
    httpTransport.debug = true;

    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    httpTransport.requestDump

    httpTransport.responseDump
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is having the same problem I fixed it with the `trim()` method.

`Log.d("TAG ", ""+(androidHttpTransport.requestDump).trim());`

PD: Maybe the op wasn't calling a print method.

Comment: Thanks, this is great